# Why are changes on a copy of a struct reflecting on original struct in go?

Tags: go

I am confused about pass by value in Go. I am doing this;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type point struct {
    x    int
    list []int
}

func main() {
    p := point{20, []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

    fmt.Printf("Address: %p, Value: %v\n", &p, p)
    passByValue(p, 1)
    fmt.Printf("Address: %p, Value: %v\n", &p, p)

}

func passByValue(copyOfP point, i int) {
    copyOfP.list = append(copyOfP.list[:i], copyOfP.list[i+1:]...)
    fmt.Printf("From passByValue Address: %p, Value: %v\n", &copyOfP, copyOfP)
}
```

Output:

```
Original p Address: 0xc00000c080, Value: {20 [1 2 3 4 5]}
passByValue copyOfP Address: 0xc00000c0c0, Value: {20 [1 3 4 5]}
Original p Address: 0xc00000c080, Value: {20 [1 3 4 5 5]}
```

shouldn't `copyOfP` be a copy of `p` and not reflect on original `p` what so ever.

Whats happening here?

Comment: copyOfP is a copy of p and nothing in your code or output hints at anything contradicting this fact.

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go and read the blog post about slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
func main() {

    // history.ReadlineTest()

    p := point{20, []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

    fmt.Printf("Address: %p, Value: %v\n", &p.list[0], p)
    passByValue(p, 1)
    fmt.Printf("Address: %p, Value: %v\n", &p.list[0], p)
}

func passByValue(copyOfP point, i int) {
    copyOfP.list = append(copyOfP.list[:i], copyOfP.list[i+1:]...)
    fmt.Printf("From passByValue Address: %p, Value: %v\n", &copyOfP.list[0], copyOfP)
}
```

```
Address: 0xc00001a0c0, Value: {20 [1 2 3 4 5]}
From passByValue Address: 0xc00001a0c0, Value: {20 [1 3 4 5]}
Address: 0xc00001a0c0, Value: {20 [1 3 4 5 5]}
```

The "list" slice reused the same memory.

Comment: Awesome. What would be the way to make a true copy of this struct that don't overlap what so ever?

Comment: @Nagri It depends. A possible but not recommended way is to marshal and unmarshal your point.

Comment: @Nagri: for solutions, look for "deep copy" for Go, like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790190/quicker-way-to-deepcopy-objects-in-golang or this post: https://flaviocopes.com/go-copying-structs/