# Efficient hash of string concatenation in go

Tags: go

I need to make function that calculating hash of multiple large strings concatenation. How to do it efficient in go? To avoid unnecessary memory copies

*I updated the question*. Now the question is there a difference between make_hash and make_hash_ptr

```go
func make_hash(v ...string) string {
    h := sha256.New()
    for _, s := range v {
        h.Write([]byte(s))
    }
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func make_hash_ptr(v ...*string) string {
    h := sha256.New()
    for _, s := range v {
        h.Write([]byte(*s))
    }
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func main() {
    s1 := "very large string...."
    s2 := "very large string...."
    s3 := "very large string...."
    hash := make_hash(s1, s2, s3)

    fmt.Println(hash)
}
```

Comment: Don't concatenate strings. Write them one-by-one into the hasher. The result is the same.

Comment: Thank you! Does it matter in that case if the parameter is a string or a pointer to a string?

Comment: this seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156856/hashing-multiple-values-in-golang

Comment: Passing string pointers is unnecessary as strings are already headers pointing to the actual string data, and strings are immutable.

Comment: If you are going to concatenate a big amount of string, you are penalizing yourself making it a slice in `make_hash(v ...string) string`

Comment: i dwonvot because this is too simplistic/convoluted. We dont know how the data is read, or arranged in the source.

Comment: If you MUST concatenate large strings, then the strings.Builder package is the way to go for efficiency. https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Builder

Comment: Are you concerned with `make_hash("ab", "c")` to produce the same result as `make_hash("a", "bc")`? If yes, you need to combine hashes by yourself, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76693851/1943849